# Permutation unitary in a tensor product

Tags: matrices, permutations, representation-theory, tensor-products

Given a matrix of the form

$$ A = B_{1} \otimes B_{2} \otimes B_{3} \otimes... \otimes B_{n} $$

how can I find a matrix that gives me a permutation of , say, two of the elements:

$$ A = B_{2} \otimes B_{3} \otimes B_{1} \otimes... \otimes B_{n} $$

I would like to be able to find a general matrix that does  a chosen permutation for a kronecker product of n matrices.